# Map value is not getting increased when it finds duplicate key. Please advise

Tags: hashmap

I am new to Java.. Please help me to get required output for the below code.
Map value has to be counted when month value is repeated

Issue occurs due to 2 sublist which is executing on a different threads. Please advise if there is any modification needs to be done in this code in order to rectify map value to get counted.

```
int size = inputList.size();
int listSize = size/numberOfThreads;
List<String> tmplist1 = inputList.subList(0, listSize);
int count = listSize;
for (int i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++)
{

        if(listSize <= size) {
            t1 = new TotalOrderThread();    
         t1.setInput(tmplist1);
        Thread thread = new Thread(t1);
         thread.start();
         thread.join();
        if(listSize < size)
        tmplist1 = inputList.subList(listSize, listSize+count);
        listSize=listSize+count;
        }
```

*

```
Input:
123,03/04/2005
234,04/05/2005
567,03/04/2005
789,01/01/2005
```

Output:(month 4 is repeated twice but the value is not getting counted as 2). Please help to find out the mistake. Also, Is there anyway to print the month value as "MMM" format while iterating map?

```
4    1
5    1
1    1
4    1
```

*

```
Map<Integer,Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<this.input.size();i++)
{
String details  = input.get(i);
String[] detailsarr = details.split(",");
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate id = LocalDate.parse(detailsarr[1], f);
int month = id.getMonthValue();
if(orderMap.containsKey(month))
{
int count = orderMap.get(month);
orderMap.put(month, count+1);
}

else
{
orderMap.put(month, 1);

 }
 }
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : orderMap.entrySet())
{
int month3 = entry.getKey();
int value = entry.getValue();
System.out.println(month3+ "    " +value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code like below. This one works.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();

String[] input  = {"123,03/04/2005", "234,04/05/2005", "567,03/04/2005", "789,01/01/2005"};

for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
{
    String details  = input[i];

    String[] detailsarr = details.split(",");
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
    LocalDate id = LocalDate.parse(detailsarr[1], f);
    int month = id.getMonthValue();

    if(orderMap.containsKey(month))
    {
        int count = orderMap.get(month);
        orderMap.put(month, count+1);
    }

    else
    {
        orderMap.put(month, 1);

    }
 }

 for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : orderMap.entrySet())
 {
    int month3 = entry.getKey();
    int value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(month3+ "    " +value);
 }
```